# how can we Add Parallax Scrolling in Cocos 2D?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocos2d-iphone

how can we Add Parallax Scrolling in Cocos 2D version 3 (IOS) . I have explored many tutorials but nothing has helped me. i have tried following code but its not working . can you please list down steps to achieve Parallax Scrolling in Cocos2D game. i ma newbie in game Development . your help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

```
CCParallaxNode *voidNode = [CCParallaxNode node];
[voidNode addChild:bg4 z:1 parallaxRatio:ccp(3.5f, 3.5f) positionOffset:ccp(3.5f, 3.5f)];
[voidNode addChild:_spacedust1 z:2 parallaxRatio:ccp(3.5f, 3.5f) positionOffset:ccp(3.5, 3.5)];
[self addChild:voidNode];
```

Answer (score 1):

You just move the `voidNode`. All children that you add to voidNode will be moved relative to `voidNode`.

So for example the foreground should be moved exactly like the `voidNode` then you make a parallaxRatio of `ccp(1.f, 1.f)`.

Then the background for example should be moved slower than the foreground you make a parallaxRatio of `ccp(0.6f, 0.6f)`.